# Best way for cutting fields from hadoop files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, cloudera-cdh

I have several files in my hadoop cluster, about 2000 fields in each file.  I need a quick way of cutting specific fields out of each file and creating a new file for sftping to a client.

eg. I have 20 files with fields from 1 to 2000
From each file I need to pull fields 1,6,7,777,545,345,655,1004 etc, in that order.

I need to do this every day and have several processes selecting different fields to use.

Interested in hearing what other peoples suggestions would be for best technology to use to do that?

- Use hive query to select all the required fields
- Use mapreduce Use
- spark to run hive
- or mapreduce Something else completely different

Thanks,
Red

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use Apache Pig. The source files can be loaded into Pig and as you know the indexes of extracting fields, you can use those indexes to extract from Apache Pig relations (loaded files). Indexes start from 0 in Pig.
See following link for more details about loading and extracting fields in Apache Pig

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#LOAD

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use awk commands to slice your files (specify appropriate delimiter) and pipe the command accordingly.

An ideal syntax may somewhat look like:

```
hdfs dfs -cat <filename> | awk -F"," {print insert_columns_here} > output_file
```

Comment: Alternatively, you may also use Hadoop streaming to achieve projecting columns from files in HDFS using mapper function by creating an awk statement as described above.

Answer (score -2):

I'd use hive's "create external table as select".